# Confusion regarding protobufs

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers

I have a server that makes frequent calls to microservices (actually AWS Lambda functions written in python) with raw JSON payloads and responses on the order of 5-10 MB. These payloads are gzipped to bring their total size under lambda's 6MB limit.

Currently payloads are serialized to JSON, gzipped, and sent to Lambda. The responses are then gunzipped, and deserialized from JSON back into Java POJOs.

Via profiling we have found that this process of serializing, gzipping, gunzipping, and deserializaing is the majority of our servers CPU usage by a large margin. Looking into ways to make serialization more efficient led me to protobufs.

Switching our serialization from JSON to protobufs would certainly make our (de)serialization more efficient, and might also have the added benefit of eliminating the need to gzip to get payloads under 6MB (network latency is not a concern here).

The POJOs in question look something like this (Java):

```
public class InputObject {

    ... 5-10 metadata fields containing primitives or other simple objects ...

    List<Slots> slots; // usually around 2000
}

public class Slot {
    public double field1;     //20ish fields with a single double
    public double[] field2;   //10ish double arrays of length 5
    public double[][] field3; //1 2x2 matrix of doubles
}
```

This is super easy with JSON, `gson.toJson(inputObj)` and you're good to go. Protobufs seem like a whole different beast, requiring you to use the generated classes and litter your code with stuff like

```
Blah blah = Blah.newBuilder()
    .setFoo(f)
    .setBar(b)
    .build()
```

Additionally, this results in an immutable object which requires more hoop jumping to update. Just seems like a bad bad thing to put all that transport layer dependent code into the business logic.

I have seen some people recommend writing wrappers around the generated classes so that all the protobuffy-ness doesn't leak into the rest of the codebase and that seemed like a good idea. But then I am not sure how I could serialize the top level `InputObject` in one go.

Maybe protobufs aren't the right tool for the job here, but it seems like the go-to solution for inter-service communication when you start looking into improving efficiency.

Am I missing something?

Comment: with the wrapper objects, why can't you serialize / deserialize the underlying proto when required? what do you mean by "in one go"?

Comment: No, all of this is perfectly normal, and it's not really that bad.  Honestly, using builders and immutable objects is good practice anyway.  Building wrapper classes is normal, too, and you build proto to/from conversions all the way down.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I guess I'm just not really grokking the wrapper implementation. I already have a class that is used extensively throughout the code. Further, these classes are from an external jar (I do not control this code). It seems like using protos would require me to essentially duplicate the existing class structure in a `.proto` file, and iterate through my entire object to create a proto version for serializing?

Comment: @muzzlator I guess I just don't understand what a wrapper class would even begin to look like. I see people mentioning it, but haven't been able to find any examples online.

Comment: Honestly -- yes, that's about what you'd do.

Comment: @LouisWasserman okay that makes sense. I guess iterating to build the proto is insignificant overhead (comparable to a JDBC row mapper?) compared to the potential gains. That also, keeps transport logic out of the business logic. Only downside is maintaining the wrapper in conjunction with the proto, but I suppose thats no different from maintaining the main class in conjunction with the documented API. Actually makes it safer as failure to comply with the proto (which defines the API) results in a compilation error. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

with your proto you can always serialize in one-go. You have an example in the java tuto online:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial

```
AddressBook.Builder addressBook = AddressBook.newBuilder();
...
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(args[0]);
addressBook.build().writeTo(output);
```

Also what you might want to do, is to serialize your proto into a ByteArray, and then encode it in Base64 to carry it through your wrapper:

```
String yourPayload = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(blah.toByteArray())
```

You have additional library that can help you to transform existing JSON into a proto, such as JsonFormat:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/JsonFormat

And the usage is straightforward as well:
to serialize as Json:

```
JsonFormat.printToString(yourProto)
```

To build from a proto:

```
JsonFormat.merge(yourJSONstring, yourPrototBuilder);
```

No need to iterate through each element of the object.

Let me know if this answer your question!

Comment: I understand the concept of nested protos portrayed in the tutorial, but it seems like that would require actually using the proto generated classes as my data models. that would require thousands of lines of rewrite. I am still very unclear how to transition from simply serializing my existing classes into JSON (dead simple) to utilizing protobufs for serialization.

Comment: Yes, this is the idea. Using the proto as your data model. If you know in advance the structure of your data, you could still write a script to generate your proto descriptor.

Comment: This still seems like it requires changing business logic to accomodate the transportation layer. For example my `Slot` object contains a few fields that are nullable `Double` types as well as 2d arrays, neither of which are supported by protobuf. It makes sense if we would have designed the server around protobufs in the first place, but I'm just not understanding how we can now "switch to protobuf" from json without a massive rewrite effort.